# Why can't I input it at once and output it?

Tags: python

This code was run through Atom.

Why can't I input it once and then output it?

Once the desired temperature is entered, the converted temperature should be output.

Conditions: Keep Three Functions, Using a main function to run three functions

```
def main():
    print("This program converts Celsius into fahrenheit.")
    print("============================")
    # ===Modify codes below=================
    celsius_value = input_celsius_value()
    fahrenheit_value = convert_celsius_fahrenheit(celsius_value)
    print_fahrenheit_value(celsius_value, fahrenheit_value)
    print("===========================")
    print("Program has ended.")

def input_celsius_value():
    celsius_value = float(input("Enter desired temperature to convert.: "))
    return celsius_value

def convert_celsius_fahrenheit(fahrenheit_value):
    celsius_value = float(input())
    fahrenheit_value = ((9/5) * float(celsius_value)) + 32
    return fahrenheit_value

def print_fahrenheit_value(celsius_value, fahrenheit_value):
    celsius_value = input_celsius_value()
    fahrenheit_value = convert_celsius_fahrenheit(fahrenheit_value)
    print("Centigrade temperature :", celsius_value)
    print("fahrenheit temperature :", fahrenheit_value)
    return print_fahrenheit_value

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `convert_celsius_fahrenheit` method you are taking user input for celsius value again which is not required as you have already taken the user input in `input_celsius_value` method and have stored the provided value in `celsius_value` variable in `main` method while doing `celsius_value = input_celsius_value()`.

Similarly in your `print_fahrenheit_value` method you are calling `input_celsius_value` method and `convert_celsius_fahrenheit` which are again taking a user input for celsius value.

So in all, you are taking user input four times and doing celsius to fahrenheit conversion twice.

Moreover your `convert_celsius_fahrenheit` method should take celsius value as an argument.

Change your `convert_celsius_fahrenheit` and `print_fahrenheit_value` methods to something like this:

```
def convert_celsius_fahrenheit(celsius_value):
    return 9 / 5 * celsius_value + 32

def print_fahrenheit_value(celsius_value, fahrenheit_value):
    print("Centigrade temperature :", celsius_value)
    print("fahrenheit temperature :", fahrenheit_value)
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me a solutions. I feel much better now.

Answer (score 0):

In your `print_fahrenheit_values` function, you have called the other two functions a second time. Once a variable has been `returned` you don't need to call the function again.

This is what the code should be:

```
def print_fahrenheit_value(celsius_value, fahrenheit_value): 
    # you have the variables already ^^^^^^^^^^^

    print("Centigrade temperature :", celsius_value)

    print("fahrenheit temperature :", fahrenheit_value)

    return print_fahrenheit_value
```

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)

Comment: @HoldenNowell if it has been resolved, please mark the correct answer using the checkbox to the left.